# Why do I occasionally see a lenticular cloud when there's no mountains for hundreds of miles?

Tags: meteorology

Very rarely in the USA Northern Mid West, maybe once a year at most, I will see a very smooth, concave cloud floating over the sky that looks exactly like a lenticular cloud, and only a few minutes, it starts to dissipate. What would explain this phenomena?

Comment: a photo or two would help strengthen your question

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_cloud shows one expired reference to something that suggest that shear winds created by fronts might be the reason.

Comment: There's definitely a lot of storm fronts in my area throughout the year, I've definitely seen a lot of weird and uniquely shaped clouds, but none as rare as the lenticular.

Comment: Is there a lake in that direction, sometimes lakes can alter the winds around them.

Comment: Will develop an answer if I can find time. Mountain waves are anchored to a ridge but can excite a wave that extends hundreds of miles downwind. At the leaks of the wave anywhere along it where the moisture is right you can get clouds like you have seen.

Comment: @John yes they usually appear right above or near the large lakes in my area.